# How to toggle visibility of NSSplitView subView + hide Pane Splitter divider?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, toggle, nssplitview

We have a parent `Split` view (`NSSplitView`), and two subviews, `Content` and `SideBar` (the sidebar is on the right).

What would be the optimal Cocoa-friendly way to toggle the `SideBar` view?

- I would really love it, if the suggested solution includes animation
- I really don't need any suggestions related to external plugins, etc (e.g. BWToolkit)

**HINT :** I've been trying to do that, but still I had issues hiding the divider of the NSSplitView as well. How could I do it, while hiding it at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a pretty decent tutorial that shows how to do this: [Unraveling the Mysteries of NSSplitView](http://www.manicwave.com/blog/2009/12/31/unraveling-the-mysteries-of-nssplitview-part-2/).

Hiding the divider is done in NSSplitView's delegate method [splitView:shouldHideDividerAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSSplitViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSplitViewDelegate/splitView%3ashouldHideDividerAtIndex%3a).

You will have to animate the frame size change yourself if you don't like the way NSSplitView does it.

Comment: `shouldHideDividerAt` only works if the divider is at the edge of the split view, not if it is between 2 panes.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way to do it is as follows - and it's animated: [**SWIFT 5**]

```
    splitViewItems[1].animator().isCollapsed = false // Show side pane
    splitViewItems[1].animator().isCollapsed = true // hide side pane
```

Comment: This answer uses `NSSplitViewController`.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a Swift version of the content in the link from @Nathan's answer that works for me. In the context of my example `splitView` is set elsewhere, probably as an instance property on an encompassing class:

```
func toggleSidebar () {
    if splitView.isSubviewCollapsed(splitView.subviews[1] as NSView) {
        openSidebar()
    } else {
        closeSidebar()
    }
}

func closeSidebar () {
    let mainView = splitView.subviews[0] as NSView
    let sidepanel = splitView.subviews[1] as NSView
    sidepanel.hidden = true
    let viewFrame = splitView.frame
    mainView.frame.size = NSMakeSize(viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height)
    splitView.display()
}

func openSidebar () {
    let sidepanel = splitView.subviews[1] as NSView
    sidepanel.hidden = false
    let viewFrame = splitView.frame
    sidepanel.frame.size = NSMakeSize(viewFrame.size.width, 200)
    splitView.display()
}
```

These functions will probably methods in a class, they are for me. If your `splitView` can be `nil` you obviously have to check for that. This also assumes you have two subviews and the one at index 1, here as `sidePanel` is the one you want to collapse.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 9.0 with Storyboards open Application Scene select View->Menu->Show sidebar. CTRL-click Show Sidebar, in sent actions delete the provided one, click on x. From the circle CTRL drag to First Responder in application scene and select toggleSideBar to connect to. Open storyboard and select the first split view item and in attributes inspector change behaviour from default to sidebar. Run and try with view menu item show/hide. All done in interface builder no code. toggleSideBar handles the first split view item. https://github.com/Dis3buted/SplitViewController

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this can be extended to work with two different sidebars?

Answer (score 3):

I got some artifacts with the code above, likely because it was out of context. I am sure it works where it was meant to. Anyway, here is a very streamlined implementation:

```
// this is the declaration of a left vertical subview of
// 'splitViewController', which is the name of the split view's outlet

var leftView: NSView {
    return self.splitViewController.subviews[0] as NSView
    }

// here is the action of a button that toggles the left vertical subview
// the left subview is always restored to 100 pixels here

@IBAction func someButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if splitViewController.isSubviewCollapsed(leftView) {
        splitViewController.setPosition(100, ofDividerAtIndex: 0)
        leftView.hidden = false
    } else {
        splitViewController.setPosition(0, ofDividerAtIndex: 0)
        leftView.hidden = true
    }
}
```

To see a good example using animations, control-click to download [this file](https://github.com/mdiep/MDPSplitView/blob/master/MDPSplitViewDemo/MainWindowController.swift).

Answer (score 1):

If your `NSSplitView` control is part of a `NSSplitViewController` object, then you can simply use this:

```
splitViewController.toggleSidebar(nil)
```